# Create a matrix from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I want to create a  matrix from a function, such that the `(3,3)` matrix C has values equal to 1 if the row index is smaller than a given threshold k.

```
import numpy as np

k = 3
C = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: 1 if i < k else 0, (3,3))
```

However, this piece of code throws an error

> "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()" and I do not really understand why.

Comment: Create an array of zeros `c=np.zeros((3,3))`, then `c[:k,:]=1`?

Comment: That would work, but I am interested in the nature of this error.

Comment: Huh? Surely `l = lambda i,j: 1 if i < k else 0` and `C = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(l), (5,3))`

Comment: np.fromfunction just creats a grid, and passes the whole thing to your function with one call. Look at its code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for `fromfunction` is:

```
dtype = kwargs.pop('dtype', float)
args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

You see it calls `function` just once - with the whole array of `indices`.  It is not iterative.

```
In [672]: idx = np.indices((3,3))                                                    
In [673]: idx                                                                        
Out[673]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

Your lambda expects scalar `i,j` values, not a 3d array

```
 lambda i,j: 1 if i < k else 0
```

`idx<3` is a 3d boolean array.  The error arises when that is use in an `if` context.

`np.vectorize` or `np.frompyfunc` is better if you want to apply a scalar function to a set of arrays:

```
In [677]: np.vectorize(lambda i,j: 1 if i < 2 else 0)(idx[0],idx[1])                 
Out[677]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

However it isn't faster than more direct iterative approaches, and way slower than functions that operation on whole arrays.

One of many whole-array approaches:

```
In [680]: np.where(np.arange(3)[:,None]<2, np.ones((3,3),int), np.zeros((3,3),int))  
Out[680]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @MarkSetchell you need to [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize) your function:

```
k = 3
f = lambda i,j: 1 if i < k else 0

C = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (3,3))
```

and you get:

```
C
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: He also suggested shaping with 5 rows so you can see and check the result!

Comment: @MarkSetchell He is brilliant, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `np.fromfunction` does not iterate over all elements, it only returns the indices in each dimension. You can use `np.where()` to apply a condition based on those indices, choosing from two alternatives depending on the condition:

```
import numpy as np

k = 3
np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: np.where(i < k, 1, 0), (5,3))
```

which gives:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

This avoids naming the lambda without things becoming too unwieldy. On my laptop, this approach was about 20 times faster than `np.vectorize()`.