# `numpy` - One-liner matrix generation from vectorized function?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, fractals

I've been working on a program in python that generates a zoom on a Mandelbrot set by generating all frames and combining them using `ffmpeg`.

In order to generate said frames, I'm using three matrices, each one of them storing r,g,b values respectively, then combining them with `np.dstack((r,g,b))` and saving the result as an image using `PIL.Image`.

Here's how I create the RGB matrices :

```py
def fract(self,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,iters):
    width = self.data['width']
    height = self.data['height']
    xpix = (xmax-xmin)/width
    ypix = (ymax-ymin)/height
    r,g,b = [np.zeros((height,width),dtype=np.int8) for i in range(3)]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r[y,x] = self.color(self.mandelbrot(xmin+(x*xpix),ymin+(y*ypix),iters),iters,0)
            g[y,x] = self.color(self.mandelbrot(xmin+(x*xpix),ymin+(y*ypix),iters),iters,1)
            b[y,x] = self.color(self.mandelbrot(xmin+(x*xpix),ymin+(y*ypix),iters),iters,2)
    self.im = np.dstack((r,g,b))
```

So first I define some useful variables (image width/height, size of a pixel in coordinates, number of iterations) and I modify every matrix value by value.
Now, this system is very unoptimized and kinda slow so I wanted to see if it were possible to generate the three matrices already containing what I want to save some time in fractal calculations.

So I tried to see if I could generate `r` with `np.fromfunction` like this :

```py
r = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(lambda i,j: self.color(self.mandelbrot(xmin+(j*xpix),ymin+(i*ypix),iters),iters,0)),(height,width),dtype=np.int8)
```

But when I do this, turns out the matrices aren't equal. Most of the calculated values are off compared to what I should otherwise be getting.
Is there something wrong with the way I'm using vectorialization, or `fromfunction` as a whole ?

Here are the `color` and `mandelbrot` functions as well

```py
#Calculates color depending on Mandelbrot iterations
#n = iteration
#iters = max iter
#col = color (0 = red, 1 = green, 2 = blue)
def color(self,n,iters,col):
    if n in [0,iters]: return (0,0,0)[col]
    return self.palette[n%len(self.palette)][col]
```

```py
#Calculates Mandelbrot iterations
#real = Real part of c
#imag = Imaginary part of c
#iters = Max iteration
def mandelbrot(self,real,imag,iters):
    c = complex(real,imag)
    z = 0.0j
    for i in range(iters):
        z = (z**2)+c
        if (((z.real)**2) + ((z.imag)**2)) >= 4: return i
    return iters
```

Comment: Look at the code of `fromfunction`. It's not a 'vectorizor'. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55865031/901925

Comment: I know it isn't, but I used it on the `vectorize()` of the `self.color(self.mandelbrot(*args))`, so wouldn't it be applied to the entire vectorized function properly ? Am I missing the point of `vectorize` with `fromfunction` ?

Comment: I was just able to look at your `np.fromfunction` use on the computer, and take it apart.  It's not very readable.  Off hand it looks like you are using it right.  That is `(height,width)` when passed to `np.indices` should generate the same indices as you get with the `x` and `y` loops.  I can't speak for the error you get (which you only describe in vague terms).  But regardless, I'm sure that approach isn't going to help performance.  `np.vectorize` doesn't promise speed.  And 3 iterations isn't going to be faster than your combined one.

Comment: Yeah, I think it shouldn't help performance that much more, but I wanted to see if I could then use `numba` `@vectorize` decorators on the matrix generation, allowing Python to work with CUDA-compatible graphic cards to parallelize calculations, because it didn't appreciate the `for` loops. I'll see if I can fix the error some way.

Comment: So, I figured it out randomly ! Apparently I shouldn't have specified `dtype=np.int8` as keyword to `np.fromfunction` because it makes false calculations somehow. Instead, I had to add keyword arg `otypes=[np.int8]` to `np.vectorize` to enforce `np.int8` data type and the matrices are now correctly generated !